# Why my react components don't behave independently?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

so i have a wrapper component with a button which produce its children component whenever clicked no matter how many times. it is a wrapper component and i want to use it how many times i need but everytime i switch from one to another its state will reset. i switch in this piece of code: (in summary there are divs when you click on each one of them they show the respective handler)

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./../styles/left.css";
import rightIcon from "./../assets/right.svg";
import General from "./general";
import Educational from "./educational";
import Professional from "./professional";
import Handler from "./handler";


export default function Left({ data, onChange }) {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(0);
  return (
    <div className="forms">
      <div className="form-type">
        <div className="general-btn" onClick={() => setSelected(0)}>
          general information{" "}
          {selected === 0 ? <img src={rightIcon} alt="" /> : ""}{" "}
        </div>
        <div className="educational-btn" onClick={() => setSelected(1)}>
          educational experience{" "}
          {selected === 1 ? <img src={rightIcon} alt="" /> : ""}
        </div>
        <div className="practical-btn" onClick={() => setSelected(2)}>
          practical experience{" "}
          {selected === 2 ? <img src={rightIcon} alt="" /> : ""}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="form">
      {selected === 0 ? <General data={data} onChange={onChange} /> : ""}{" "}
      {selected === 1 ? <Handler> <Educational data={data} onChange={onChange}/> </Handler> : ""}{" "}
      {selected === 2 ? <Handler> <Professional data={data} onChange={onChange}/></Handler> : ""}{" "}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

and it is my handler component:

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function Handler({children}){
    const [childrens, setChildrens] = useState([]);

  const addChild = () => {
    setChildrens(prevChildren => [...prevChildren, children]);
  };
    return(
        <div>
            {childrens}
            <button onClick={addChild}>add</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

i thought the states are independent in each component but i see otherwise. why?

also i tried to lift my state up from my handler component but this way i have to repeat myself and i hate doing it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `Handler` component state resets because when the `selected` state updates the `Handler` components are conditionally rendered; only the active `Handler` is mounted, the other are unmounted. When `Handler` remounts it will start with the initial state.

To address this you will need to lift the state up to a common ancestor component that remains mounted while these `Handler` components are conditionally rendered so their state can be "restored" when they remount.

An example solution would be to store the children "counts" in state in the `Left` component.

```
function Left({ data, onChange }) {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(0);
  const [counts, setCounts] = useState({});

  const addHandler = (id) =>
    setCounts((counts) => ({
      ...counts,
      [id]: (counts[id] ?? 0) + 1
    }));

  return (
    <div className="forms">
      <div className="form-type">
        <div className="general-btn" onClick={() => setSelected(0)}>
          general information
          {selected === 0 && <img src={rightIcon} alt="" />}
        </div>
        <div className="educational-btn" onClick={() => setSelected(1)}>
          educational experience
          {selected === 1 && <img src={rightIcon} alt="" />}
        </div>
        <div className="practical-btn" onClick={() => setSelected(2)}>
          practical experience
          {selected === 2 && <img src={rightIcon} alt="" />}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="form">
        {selected === 0 && <General data={data} onChange={onChange} />}
        {selected === 1 && (
          <Handler count={counts[1]} onAdd={() => addHandler(1)}>
            <Educational data={data} onChange={onChange} />
          </Handler>
        )}
        {selected === 2 && (
          <Handler count={counts[2]} onAdd={() => addHandler(2)}>
            <Professional data={data} onChange={onChange} />
          </Handler>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Update `Handler` to initialize the `childrens` state to the number of saved children count, and call the `onAdd` callback to increment the count each time a new child is added.

```
import { cloneElement, useState } from "react";
import { nanoid } from "nanoid";

function Handler({ children, count, onAdd }) {
  const [childrens, setChildrens] = useState(
    Array.from({ length: count }, () =>
      cloneElement(children, { key: nanoid() })
    )
  );

  const addChild = () => {
    onAdd();
    setChildrens((prevChildren) => [
      ...prevChildren,
      cloneElement(children, { key: nanoid() })
    ]);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={addChild}>add</button>
      {childrens}
    </div>
  );
}
```

### Demo

```js
const rightIcon = "";

const nanoid = () => Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15) + Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15);

const General = () => <h1>General</h1>;
const Educational = () => <h1>Educational</h1>;
const Professional = () => <h1>Professional</h1>;

function Handler({ children, count, onAdd }) {
  const [childrens, setChildrens] = React.useState(
    Array.from({ length: count }, () =>
      React.cloneElement(children, { key: nanoid() })
    )
  );

  const addChild = () => {
    onAdd();
    setChildrens((prevChildren) => [
      ...prevChildren,
      React.cloneElement(children, { key: nanoid() })
    ]);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={addChild}>add</button>
      {childrens}
    </div>
  );
}

function Left({ data, onChange }) {
  const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState(0);
  const [counts, setCounts] = React.useState({});

  const addHandler = (id) =>
    setCounts((counts) => ({
      ...counts,
      [id]: (counts[id] || 0) + 1
    }));

  return (
    <div className="forms">
      <div className="form-type">
        <div className="general-btn" onClick={() => setSelected(0)}>
          general information
          {selected === 0 && <img src={rightIcon} alt="" />}
        </div>
        <div className="educational-btn" onClick={() => setSelected(1)}>
          educational experience
          {selected === 1 && <img src={rightIcon} alt="" />}
        </div>
        <div className="practical-btn" onClick={() => setSelected(2)}>
          practical experience
          {selected === 2 && <img src={rightIcon} alt="" />}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="form">
        {selected === 0 && <General data={data} onChange={onChange} />}
        {selected === 1 && (
          <Handler count={counts[1]} onAdd={() => addHandler(1)}>
            <Educational data={data} onChange={onChange} />
          </Handler>
        )}
        {selected === 2 && (
          <Handler count={counts[2]} onAdd={() => addHandler(2)}>
            <Professional data={data} onChange={onChange} />
          </Handler>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Left />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

Comment: i learned so many new things here thanks! and it works fine now!

Answer (score 2):

The part

```
<div className="form">
  {selected === 0 && <General data={data} onChange={onChange} />}
  {selected === 1 && <Handler><Educational data={data} onChange={onChange} /></Handler>}
  {selected === 2 && <Handler><Professional data={data} onChange={onChange} /></Handler>}
</div>
```

is equivalent to

```
<div className="form">
  {selected === 0
    ? <General data={data} onChange={onChange} />
    : (
      <Handler>
        {selected === 1
          ? <Educational data={data} onChange={onChange} />
          : <Professional data={data} onChange={onChange}/>
        }
      </Handler>
    )
  }
</div>
```

for all purposes - they render the same element tree. (I've ignored the empty/space strings, I don't think they matter for React's component reconciliation algorithm).

So when you switch between options `1` and `2`, there's still a `<Handler>` element, and [React renders the same component with its existing state](https://react.dev/learn/preserving-and-resetting-state). If that's not what you expect, you should be able to fix this by giving the elements different `key`s:

```
<div className="form">
  {selected === 0 && <General key={0} data={data} onChange={onChange} />}
  {selected === 1 && <Handler key={1}><Educational data={data} onChange={onChange} /></Handler>}
  {selected === 2 && <Handler key={2}><Professional data={data} onChange={onChange} /></Handler>}
</div>
```

---

You'll probably have a similar problem later with the `childrens` inside `Handler` - when you copy the `children` into your array you'll probably want to give it a unique id so that you can (re)move/reorder the `childrens` individually later; use [`cloneElement`](https://react.dev/reference/react/cloneElement) for that.

Comment: oh now i get it thanks for explanation! however i added keys but it worked like before